# How to fix error 'Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable' in the css javascript toolbox plugin for wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

I am getting errors in my apache log on the plugin called CSS Javascript Toolbox. The error is this:

```
PHP message: PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in .../public_html/wp-content/plugins/css-javascript-toolbox/framework/events/subjects/hook.subject.php on line 81 and 82
```

The snippet where the code is this is:

```
protected function init($name, $target, $defintion, $includes) {
    // Initialize parent!
    $return = parent::init($name, $target, $defintion, $includes);
    $this->hookName = strtolower("{$this->definition['targetClass']}_{$name}");
    // Register Wordpress Filter,
    add_action($this->getHookName(), array(&$this, 'trigger'), 10, count($this->getDefinition('parameters')));
    add_action($this->getInstanceHookName(), array(&$this, 'trigger'), 10, count($this->getDefinition('parameters')));
    return $return;
}
```

I am using PHP 7.2 and have read in some forums that if a downgrade to PHP 7.1 is done this problem might stop.

I did not want to downgrade because I have other plugins installed and all are working very well with PHP 7.2, only this one is reporting this problem.

What can I do to fix it? Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Check whether the `$this->getDefinition('parameters')` is an array? Just do `var_dump($this->getDefinition('parameters'))` for test it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Is this what you are saying?:

 protected function init($name, $target, $defintion, $includes) {
  // Initialize parent!
  $return = parent::init($name, $target, $defintion, $includes);
  $this->hookName = strtolower("{$this->definition['targetClass']}_{$name}");
  // Register Wordpress Filter,
  add_action($this->getHookName(), array(&$this, 'trigger'), 10, var_dump($this->getDefinition('parameters'));
  add_action($this->getInstanceHookName(), array(&$this, 'trigger'), 10, var_dump($this->getDefinition('parameters'));
  return $return;
 }

Comment: No. add `var_dump($this->getDefinition('parameters'));` this line before the function `add_action`. Once you printed it you can check whether its an array or not.

Comment: replace with this `add_action($this->getHookName(), array(&$this, 'trigger'), 10, count((array) $this->getDefinition('parameters')));`

Comment: Is it this way then ?:

 protected function init($name, $target, $defintion, $includes) {
  // Initialize parent!
  $return = parent::init($name, $target, $defintion, $includes);
  $this->hookName = strtolower("{$this->definition['targetClass']}_{$name}");
  // Register Wordpress Filter,
  add_action($this->getHookName(), array(&$this, 'trigger'), 10, count((array) $this->getDefinition('parameters')));;
  add_action($this->getInstanceHookName(), array(&$this, 'trigger'), 10, var_dump($this->getDefinition('parameters'));
  return $return;
 }

Comment: @wizzup this morning I took a look at the error log again and now I get this warning:

AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' in .../ line 81

Comment: I removed the plugin that was causing this error and added the function I wanted in the functions.php file of the child theme. Now everything is normal.